# python : numpy n-array : arranged values

Tags: python, numpy

i would like to get an multidimentional array in `arr1.shape = (x,y)`

which would be filled with values like from `np.arange(z)`, where `z` is number of spaces in arr1.

it is known that, that i could make
`arr2 = np.random.randn(x,y)`
but then the values would be random...

Is there any straight way, which allows me not to iterate through the array?

Comment: Read the `arange` docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `numpy.reshape` to take the result of `numpy.arange` and reshape into `(x,y)` dimensions

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = 5
>>> y = 3
>>> np.reshape(np.arange(x*y), (x,y))
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14]])
```

Comment: Great, thats neet, thank you Cory. And if i would like to start from `1` like `1-15` (not `0` like `0-14`)?

Comment: this simple for loop works. When `arrk=np.arange(32)`, `for i in arrk:     arrk[i]=i+1`
however this comprehension doesnt work `[[arrk[i]=i+1] for i in arrk]` @Cory

Comment: Then use `np.arange(1, x*y + 1)` to make a range starting from `1`